# CentOS 9 Stream SSH with PuTTy - multiline commands

Tags: bash, shell, centos, ssh, putty

I've been using CentOS versions 6, 7 and 8 for a long time. Finally, I started using CentOS 9 Stream version. It doesn't matter whether GNOME desktop version or server version (black screen), I noticed a change when I connect to these devices with putty from windows environment.

In order to send a command to the server via SSH, instead of typing manually, I saved the previously ready configuration commands in a text file and sometimes in an excel cell. When I'm going to paste a command from a text file, I'm copying multiple lines for "enter" processing. In the same way, when you copy and paste the excel cell, it detects one more line at the end and "enter" is passed. This is exactly the method I want.

But I can't do this in CentOS 9 Stream. Whether it is a single line or multiple lines from the text file, or copying and pasting a command from excel, "enter" never goes through automatically, I have to press it from the keyboard.

Is this update in CentOS 9 a shell update? How do I change this state in CentOS 9 like the app in old CentOS 6-7-8 versions?